# Recoding values of multiple variable with same suffix to new variable with different suffix in R

Tags: r

```
library(Hmisc)
install.packages("expss")
col1.5pt <- c(1,2,4,5)
col2.5pt <- c(1,2,3,4)
col3 <- c(3,4,5,1)
col4.5pt <- c(2,3,2,4)
col5 <- c(3,NA,4,5)
df<- data.frame(col1.5pt,col2.5pt,col3,col4.5pt,col5)
abc <- c("col1.5pt", "col2.5pt", "col4.5pt")
cde <- c("col1.T2b", "col2.T2b", "col4.T2b")
df[cde]<-sapply(df[abc], function(x) recode(x,1:2~1,3~2,4:5~3))
```

I have to basically recode variables of .5pt into .T2b. At the moment, I am picking these variables but since I have lots of datasets where I have to create these kinds of variables. I want something where I can pick all the variables with .5pt and recode them into .T2b. I am new to R and trying to learn to automate my code. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly you want to name new columns based on existing columns ending in ".5pt" and then apply that function to the originals to form a new values set.

```
abc <- grep("\\.5pt$", names(df), value=TRUE) #create source column names
# use double escape "\\." to match a period ; naked periods are regex wildcards

cde.new <- gsub("\\.5pt$", ".T2b", abc)  # create destination names
# fortunately yoiu can use a vector of names on the LHS of `[.]<-`

df[cde.new] <- sapply(df[abc], function(x) recode(x,1:2~1,3~2,4:5~3))
df
#------------
  col1.5pt col2.5pt col3 col4.5pt col5 col1.T2b col2.T2b col4.T2b
1        1        1    3        2    3        1        1        1
2        2        2    4        3   NA        1        1        2
3        4        3    5        2    4        3        2        1
4        5        4    1        4    5        3        3        3
```

The `grep` function uses generalized regular expressions to process character valued vectors. In its default mode it takes two arguments, the first being a pattern that defines a matching rule and the second being the vector under consideration. It returns a number that is the relative position of any character value in the vector. When `value=TRUE`, it instead returns the actual character values rather than their position. The matching rules for the pattern are defined in the R help page `?regex`. The `gsub` function (and the `sub function) match a pattern (first argument) and then substitutes new characters for the matched ones (second argument) within the vector given in the third argument.` gsub`does this at all positions matched while`sub`only does it at the first such position. Both`grep`and`gsub`details are described in the same R help page which can be found at`?grep`.

Comment: Oh man! This is really great. Thanks. Could you please explain this to me?